# Progessive or simple aspect?

Tags: aspect

Is he still smoking? vs Does he still smoke?

Which aspect would be correct, progessive or simple? In my opinion, the first question sounds somehow better, however, I think the second question is grammatically more correct, as smoking is a habit simple aspect should be used...

Comment: _Does he still smoke?_ is [generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html); _Is he still smoking?_ is ambiguous. It can refer to the duration of his current cigarette, a real progressive; or it can be generic, in which case it's identical to _Does he still smoke?_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct.

***"Does he still smoke?"*** would be clear and unambiguous, so this would be the wiser choice.  If you were waiting for someone to come back from a smoking break you may ask ***"Is he still smoking?***", which by process of elimination, I assume is not what you want to ask.

Although both questions could mean the same thing, it is generally better to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to and generalising Sam's answer:

- ***Does he still ...*** relates to an **habitual** task or action
- ***Is he still ...*** relates to a **currently ongoing** task or action

Comment: As John Lawler says, and Sam implies, the second is actually ambiguous.